# Spring-boot: Date query param string format

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot 2.0.4.RELEASE.

I'm getting this error message:

> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'quoteWarningSearchForm' on field 'from': rejected value [2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00]; codes [typeMismatch.quoteWarningSearchForm.from,typeMismatch.from,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [quoteWarningSearchForm.from,from]; arguments []; default message [from]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'from'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value '2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]

My request is like:

```
GET /portal/warnings?from=2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00
```

As you can see, `from` query param is a `Date`. My endpoint looks like:

```
public SearchResponse<MetricGroup> metrics(MetricsSearchForm form);
```

where `MetricsSearchForm` bean looks like:

```
public class MetricsSearchForm {
    private Date from;
    private Date to;
}
```

I've also tried to add:

```
public class MetricsSearchForm {

    private String app;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private Date from;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private Date to;
}
```

But it doesn't work yet.

It seems some stupid issue I don't quite get hpw to solve.

**IMPORTANT:** I've to say that I've tried with `10/10/2020` and it's parsed correctly.

Any ideas?